# Python: assigment of Dataframe to second variable, altering of the second DataFrame alters the first

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have no idea how this is happening, maybe you can help me. I'm assigning a DataFrame to a second variable and then rescaling the second DataFrame, so that every column has mean 0 and variance 1. After doing that the first Dataframe is altered in the same way?! How is this happening? I tried to do the same assignment and then putting the second variable to 0, to see if the problem is, that both variables point to the same data. But this does not alter the first DataFrame. Here is my code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

firstDF = pd.DataFrame([[1,2],[3,4]])
firstDF.columns = ['firstColumn', 'secondColumn']

secondDF=firstDF

print(firstDF)
print(secondDF)
for i in secondDF.columns:
    secondDF[i]=(secondDF[i]-np.mean(secondDF[i]))/np.std(secondDF[i])
print(firstDF)
print(secondDF)
```

The output is:

```
   firstColumn  secondColumn
0            1             2
1            3             4
   firstColumn  secondColumn
0            1             2
1            3             4
   firstColumn  secondColumn
0         -1.0          -1.0
1          1.0           1.0
   firstColumn  secondColumn
0         -1.0          -1.0
1          1.0           1.0
```

My whole understanding of coding is crumbling! Please help!

Comment: `secondDF` and `firstDF` are pointers pointing to the same object. You would need to do `secondDF = firstDF.copy()`.

Comment: As Quang Hoang said, `list` and any other class objects like `dict` or `tuple` are referred to by variables, so saying `a = list()` is really assigning a pointer to the internal list object to `a`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest that you do this:

```
firstDF=pd.DataFrame([[1,2],[3,4]])
secondDF=firstDF.copy()
```

This will create a copy as suggested by Mayank.
But I am not sure what you want to do .
Do you want to create a copy or not ?
Could you please provide a little more clarification ?

Comment: I never knew that. Is it the same in Java or Matlab? Because I never had that problem. I wanted to do a copy, as I needed to alter the object itself but also other objects accordingly. So I needed to make a copy to be able to alter other objects in the same way.

So when I do        secondDF=firstDF,      secondDF=0          firstDF is not altered, because I put the pointer secondDF to 0 instead of firstDF? But how can I make the difference between the alteration of the object that the pointer points to and the alteration of the destination of the pointer? This both happens with =

Comment: To answer the first part of your question , I frankly have don't know about Java or Matlab. But in this case, suppose you changed the value of a column and used it in a function. Then later, you realised that you need the original data again. So creating a copy actually prevents your original data from accidentally getting changed .And sorry, I have used pointers only in C++ . But I guess you don't reallly need pointers

Answer (score 1):

Do this:

```
secondDF=firstDF.copy()
```

This will create a copy of your `firstDF`. And `firstDF` would remain intact.